# How to define output parameter in Task<IActionResult>

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, task

I'm switching tech stacks so I'm a bit confused here. This function should return an object

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Search(CoinModel Coin)
{
    var date = Coin.tracking_date.ToLocalTime().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    var dateformat = DateTime.Parse(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(date + " 00:00:00.0000000"));
    var issue = await _db.Coins.SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.coin == Coin.coin.ToUpper() && c.tracking_date == dateformat);
    return issue == null ? NotFound() : Ok(issue);
}
```

But I can't seem to access the result like this

```
var search = await Search(Coin);
return search.id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a helper method.

```
private async Task<Coin> SearchAsync(CoinModel Coin)
{
    var date = Coin.tracking_date.ToLocalTime().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    var dateformat = DateTime.Parse(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(date + " 00:00:00.0000000"));
    var issue = await _db.Coins.SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.coin == Coin.coin.ToUpper() && c.tracking_date == dateformat);
    return issue == null ? NotFound() : Ok(issue);
}


public async Task<IActionResult> Search(CoinModel coin)
{
    var issue = await SearchAsync(coin);
    return issue == null ? NotFound() : Ok(issue);
}
```

I would advise you not to return your database models in your api methods. I would advise you to translate the db model in to a dto and return the dto. It may feel like a) extra effort for nothing and b) duplication, but a) it's not that much work and b) it protects you from accidentally exposing data you don't want to expose.

*Btw. In C# the convetion is to start argument with a common letter, so `CoinModel coin`, not `CoinModel Coin`.*

Answer (score 1):

You return an IActionResult in this method but your goal is to return a Coin (Entity). You should change the return type of your method.
I assume that class name of coin entity is 'Coin'

```
    [NonAction]
    public async Task<Coin> Search(CoinModel Coin)
    {
        var date = Coin.tracking_date.ToLocalTime().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        var dateformat = DateTime.Parse(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(date + " 00:00:00.0000000"));
        var issue = await _db.Coins.SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.coin == Coin.coin.ToUpper() && c.tracking_date == dateformat);
        return issue;
    }
```

By the way, as this method is not an Action method, you can define it using [NonAction]

In addition, You just want to make a search operation on a List. This means this is a 'Business Logic Layer' operation. I believe that we shouldn't do such operations in Controller as Non-Action Methods. In the business logic layer, you can use a 'Result Class' to be able to control exceptions, null returnings and errors.
You can look at this link about 'Result Class' => https://josef.codes/my-take-on-the-result-class-in-c-sharp/

Comment: `NotFound()` return not Coin.